# Trying to extract the last 2 characters from XML with XSL

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to get the last 2 Characters from the element Status. The output should be "FG" but my XSL is not working... It seems that there is something wrong with my syntax.
Can some help please? :)

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<DATA xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <Company>
        <Id>12345</Id>
        <Name>CompanyName</Name>
        <Status>ABCDEFG</Status>
    </Company>
</DATA>
```

XSL:

````
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    version="2.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/"> 
      <Account>
          <StatusXYZ><xsl:value-of select="DATA/Company/Status/substring(@Status, string-length(@Status), -2)" /></StatusXYZ>
      </Account>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>```
````

Comment: Im pretty sure that you just have to remove the ',' and subtract the 2nd argument. aka: 'substring(@Status, string-length(@Status) -2)'. If the thrid argument is empty it signals that it will take everything left of the string.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this XPath to get required output:

```
DATA/Company/Status/substring(., string-length() - 1, string-length())
```